# ¿Por qué JSON.stringify() serializa undefined como null?

Tags: javascript, json, serialización

Estoy intentando emular la función JSON.stringify haciendo un poco de "retroingenieria" viendo el resultado de serializar un objeto o array a json. A continuación pongo un jsfiddle de la emulación de un metodo propio.

```js
"use strict"

const obj = {
  "hello": "object",
  "im_an_array": ["pos 0", "pos 1"],
  22.4: [1, "Hola", null, undefined, false, 0],
  "object": {
    description: "im an object"
  },
  "date": new Date(),
  "function": function(arg = "") {
   alert("Hello "+arg+"!");
  }
}
const arr = ["Hello", "array", 2, 2.1245, ["0", 1], null, new Date(), [false, [undefined, true, {param1: true, empty_obj: {}}, {empty_arr: []}, ""]]];


/****************** START OF FUNCION *************************/

JSON.cerealize = function(obj = {}) {
    if (typeof obj !== "object") {
      throw new TypeError("The parameter passed is not an object");
    }

    let str2 = "";
    let openTag = "{";
    let closeTag = "}";
    let obj_type = "object";
    let str3 = ""; //For setting keys and ':' for only when the value is not a function.

    //KNOW IF IT IS AN ARRAY OR OBJECT FOR OPEN AND END TAGS
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) { //If the passed object is an array, susbstitute the open and close tags and set the cached obj_type as array instead of object.
      openTag = "[";
      closeTag = "]";
      obj_type = "array";
    }

    str2 += openTag;
    //If object is a Function do nothing
    for (const k in obj) {
      //Cache the obj
      const _obj = obj[k];

      //Print the key of the object if it is not an array
      str3 = "";
      if (obj_type !== "array") {
        typeof k === "string" ? str3 += ("\"" + k + "\"") : str3 += k;
        str3 += ":";
      }

      if (typeof _obj !== "function") {
        
        str2 += str3;
       
        if (typeof _obj === "object") {

          if (_obj === null) {
            str2 += null;
          } else if (_obj instanceof Date) {
            str2 += "\"" + _obj.toJSON() + "\"";
          } else {
            str2 += JSON.cerealize(_obj);
          }
          
        }
        else if(typeof _obj === "string") {
           str2 += "\"" + _obj + "\"";
        } 
        else if(typeof _obj === "undefined") {
      str2 += null;
        }
        else {
          str2 += _obj;
        }
        str2 += ",";
      }
      
    }
  
    str2 += closeTag;
    return str2.replace(/,(]|})/, "$1");
  }

  /**************************** END OF FUNCTION *************************/

window.onload = function() {
  console.time('json_stringify_obj');
  JSON.stringify(obj);
  console.timeEnd('json_stringify_obj');
  
  const p_obj = document.querySelector("#info_obj");
  p_obj.textContent = JSON.cerealize(obj);

const p_arr = document.querySelector("#info_arr");
  p_arr.textContent = JSON.cerealize(arr);

}

console.time('json_stringify_arr');
  JSON.stringify(arr);
  console.timeEnd('json_stringify_arr');
 console.time('serial_obj');
  JSON.cerealize(obj);
  console.timeEnd('serial_obj');
 console.time('serial_arr');
  JSON.cerealize(arr);
  console.timeEnd('serial_arr');
```

```css
  font-family: Lucida Console, Monospace, Arial, Sans-Serif;
```

```html
<h2>
Recursion practice | Serializing objects
</h2>

<h3>serializing an object</h3>
<p id="info_obj">
  <!-- obj info -->
</p>
<hr />
<h3>
<h3>Serializing an array</h3>
<p id="info_arr">
  <!-- Array info -->
</p>
```

Me he fijado que mientras en mi caso aparece undefined, en el metodo original haciendo JSON.stringify, el valor lo serializa como null.

¿Por qué? Si undefined es un valor definible porque no se puede serializar como tal?
¿No podría guardar un objeto completamente con metodos internos? Ya que he visto que JSON.stringify no serializa los metodos.

Comment: Estos son los valores de JSON definidos en el standard: http://www.json.org/value.gif

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La respuesta corta es: **Porque así está definido JSON**

La pregunta que sigue es **¿por qué serializa Date como string?** (o cómo hago para saber si lo serializado vino de un Date o de un string que contenía ese valor como date).

La respuesta larga es: **para arreglarlo hay que programar o usar alguna librería más completa**.

Existen muchas. **JSON4all** https://www.npmjs.com/package/json4all lo hace bien para *undefined*, Date, Regexp, etc.

### En tu función

donde pones

```
    else if(typeof _obj === "undefined") {
                    str2 += null;
    }
```

dado que str2 es un string equivale a poner `str2+="null"` podrías poner por lo tanto te recomiendo probar con: `str2+="undefined"`

Hay otra cosa con la que tener cuidado, si lo que estás serializando es un string que contiene comillas no las estás "escapando" correctamente. Si

```
var a = ['hola", "chau']; 
JSON.cerialize(a);
```

te va a devolver `["hola", "chau"]` y no es lo que quieres, querrías: `["hola\", \"chau"]`

Comment: Como adición a la respuesta: undefined no es un valor válido para un JSON. Luego por convención se lleva a lo más cercano que a criterio del estándar es NULL

Comment: Gracias. La verdad es que lo hice simplemente por aprender como se podia hacer algo así. Tengo curiosidad muchas veces de como están programadas algunas de esas librerías o funciones nativas.
Le echaré un vistazo a esas librerías a como tratan los diferentes valores.

Comment: Tiene muy buena pinta json4all :-) Gracias de nuevo por la respuesta.